# Transposing Datetime Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with the following table in SQL Server, which captures the start & end date/time for which an employee worked:

```
EMP_NO  RECORD_DATE     START_TIME          END_TIME
123456  2020-07-04      10:00:00.0000000    14:30:00.0000000
```

I need to transpose the date/time values, so that it generates incremental records at 30 minute intervals with the Date/time values concatenated:

Expected Result:

```
EMP_NO  SHIFT_WORKED
123456  2020-07-04 10:00
123456  2020-07-04 10:30
123456  2020-07-04 11:00
123456  2020-07-04 11:30
123456  2020-07-04 12:00
123456  2020-07-04 12:30
123456  2020-07-04 13:00
123456  2020-07-04 13:30
123456  2020-07-04 14:00
```

Sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #HOURS (
  EMP_NO INT NOT NULL,
  RECORD_DATE DATETIME ,
  START_TIME TIME NOT NULL, 
  END_TIME TIME   NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO #HOURS 
VALUES  (123456  ,' 2020-07-04',' 10:00',' 14:30')
```

Comment: Oops, posted my answer before I noticed in your sample data that you wanted to end at `14:00`, not `14:30`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) will help you here. (I prefer to call it an "integers table"). This is just a table of integers. You can either actually have one persisted somewhere in the database, or create one "one the fly" with a CTE. There are a lot of different ways to create such a thing, some faster than others!

Once you have a tally table, you can generate any values that can be mathematically derived from that. In your case, `datetime` values in 30 minute increments. You can then join that onto your date range. Here's one way which generates a tally table as a CTE

```
with integers as (
   select     top 1000 -- as many as you need
              i = -1 + row_number() over (order by a.number) -- start from 0
   from       master..spt_values  a
   cross join master..spt_values  b   
)
select      h.emp_no,
            shift_worked = dateadd(minute, i * 30, t.startdt)
from        #hours   h
cross apply (  -- this cross apply just makes the join to integers easier to read                   
                select startdt = h.record_Date + cast(h.start_Time as datetime),
                       enddt = h.record_date + cast(h.end_time as datetime)
            )        t
join        integers i on dateadd(minute, i * 30, t.startdt) < t.enddt
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
    CREATE TABLE temp (EMP_NO  INT ,SHIFT_WORKED datetime)
    DECLARE @START_TIME TIME,@END_TIME TIME,@shift TIME,@emp int
    SELECT @START_TIME=START_TIME,@END_TIME=END_TIME,@emp=EMP_NO FROM #HOURS
    SET @shift=@START_TIME
    WHILE DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @shift) <=@END_TIME
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp  VALUES(@EMP,@shift)
    SET @Shift = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @shift)
    END
```